# how to show only subcategory name in wordpress permalink

Tags: wordpress

I set the post url structure like this:

```
/%category%/%postname%.html
```

The result is:

```
http://localhost/linux/awk/awk-index.html
```

What I want is :

```
http://localhost/awk/awk-index.html
```

Only the last subcategory name need show in the post url, how can I make it ?

Comment: Have you installed wordpress in "linux" directory?

Comment: No, linux is a top category I added, and awk is a subcategory of linux.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous solution I solved it like that:

```
add_filter( 'post_link_category', 'remove_parent_categorie_from_permalinks', 999 );
function remove_parent_categorie_from_permalinks( $category ) {
    $category->parent=0;
    return $category;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar - the opposite - challenge, I wanted only the parent category in the URL. Here is how I solved it:

```
add_filter( 'post_link_category', 'remove_child_categories_from_permalinks', 999 );
function remove_child_categories_from_permalinks( $category ) {
    while ( $category->parent ) {
        $category = get_term( $category->parent, 'category' );
    }
    return $category;
}
```

Maybe you can take this as a starting point to define your own solution?